# Access property of the object in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this $scope.data object:

```
 $scope.data = {
    '8':{
       'id':'81',
       'name':'anna',
        },
    '9':{
      'id':'82',
      'name':'sally',
       },
 };
```

I am getting the id by using for loop in this way.

```
$scope.getID = function(id){
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
    if(id == $scope.data[i].id)
      return $scope.data[i].name;
    }
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work at all. I am wondering why? Is it I call the id at the right way?

Comment: i don't think you can use $scope.data.length, as its not an array..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as its not an array of objects you can't use `$scope.data.length`, try using `for…in` loop, as:

```
for(key in $scope.data) {
    var obj = $scope.data[key];
    if( obj['id'] == id ) {
        return obj['name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to get the number of keys in your object then try use.

> Object.keys(obj).length

Answer (score 1):

It might helps you -

```
$scope.users=data;
$scope.getUserNameBYID = function(id){
    if(users !== undefined && users.length >0){
      for(key in users) {
            var obj = users[key];
            if( obj['id'] === id ) {
                return obj['name'];
            }
        }
    }
};
```